# Python Django, how to view all the content of registration for user profile. it only shows the email

Tags: python, django, user-profile

Python Django, how to view all the content of registration for user profile. it only shows the email.

views.py
def Unreg(request):

```
def loginpage(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            try:
                Userdetails=acc.objects.get(
                    Q(email=request.POST['email']) | Q(uname=request.POST['email']),
                    pwd=request.POST['pwd']
                )
                print("Username=",Userdetails)
                request.session['email']=Userdetails.email
                request.session['pwd']=Userdetails.pwd
                return render(request,'Logout.html')
            except acc.DoesNotExist as e:
                messages.success(request,' Username / Password Invalid.')
        return render(request,'Login.html')  
def logout(request):
    try:
        del request.session['email']
        uname = request.session['uname']
    except:
        return redirect('Loginpage')
    return redirect('Loginpage')
```

logout.html

```
  {{request.session.email}}
<button onclick="myFunction()"><a href="{% url 'Loginpage' %}">Logout</a></button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to logout?")) {
      } else {
      }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you print out an instance as string, like you do when you print out `print("Username=",Userdetails)`, Django calls the model `__str__ method`. Since it does print the email and it doesn't print Userdetail Object(44) or something like that, i think that you already have the `__str__` method spelled out in your model.

Then all you need to do is to go change it into something like this:

```
def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.email} - {self.password} - {self.username}"
```

Of course you have to adapt the names here to the names of the attributes in your model

If you don't know them, check out [f strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)